Memory access error when disassembling entrypoint
My task is to disassemble entrypoint using WinDbg. Via the lm (list modules) command I found a random driver, I got it HTTP.sys. Then using !dh HTTP found his image base and entry point. After folding them, I inserted the address into the disassembly tab.And windbg did not find such an address in memory. If anything, WinDbg downloaded the pdb file for this driver.

And yes, if anything, WinDbg is able to use the + operator for addresses.
After a while, I tried to disassemble the address with the u command and I made sure that the address really points to the Entrypoint of the driver:


After Googling a bit, I found solutions like .reload and !process and .process /P, but nothing helped me. Then I wanted to change the memory protect. I tried to implement this in my driver, but from the functions I found ZwProtectVirtualMemory, which eventually did not work (apparently because the address is not virtual):
ULONGLONG address = 0xFFFFF8033435E010;
SIZE_T size = 100;
ULONG oldProtect;
ZwProtectVirtualMemory(ZwCurrentProcess(), reinterpret_cast<PVOID*>(&address), &size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtect);

And memcpy also doesn't work.

Driver entry point is often located in pageable memory (pageable means that once it has been used, the system may discard the memory, putting the memory page(s) in into the swap) since it's called only once, at driver initialization. Under normal circumstances, code that would touch the page would trigger a page fault and the OS would remap the page. If you want to get the page from the kernel debugger, use .pagein

@Neitsa driver entry point usual located in discardable memory, not pageable. So you can not reload this at all. No way

I fixed my problem, it turned out the entrypoint was wrong for some reason. I found it myself through parsing the pe file and everything worked

Damn, you're absolutely right @RbMm, thanks for the heads up! I mixed up pageable vs. discardable...

I also know that you can hook the function to avoid the memory discard. But I prefer the MDL method.
